# Entityframework core 2.0, migration works only the first time

Tags: entity-framework-core

I got an issue with the migration system in EntityFramework Core 2.0, it seems to work only the first time with a database... :

When I use the command : `add-migration InitialMigration`

the migration code is generated, all works fine. But, if I use `database-update`, nothing happens...

If I change the database name in my Connection String with a random name (just add 123 for exemple), then the command `database-update` works and execute the migration in this new database...

Same problem if I try to make an other migration. Nothing happens, I have to change the database name again in order to generate the migration code.

**DbContext :**

```
public class TestProjectDbContext : DbContext
{

    public TestProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestProjectDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

}
```

**User Class (namespace TestProject.Data.Models)**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

}
```

**Connection string format (appsettings.json)**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=IPADRESS;Database=TestProject;User Id=xxxxxx; Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
```

Any idea..? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After a second look I believe that **you're running "database-update" instead of "Update-Database"**

Your code works for me as shown below.

I just grabbed your code and tested it myself with note of the service initialization in Startup.cs:

```
    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\myhost;Database=myTestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    services.AddDbContext<aDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
The database structure doesn't match, it should generate a migration code.
In my test I added a new attribute to my test class, so I should have a new column in this test table.
If I copy the database, and route the connection string to this copy, then the "add-migration" command works... But "database-update" doesn't...
Then I route again the connection string to the first database, and the "update-database" command works...
It's like I can't execute a command on the same DB more than one time... Pretty annoying !

Comment: @BenChaff Could you post your dbContext and a model class that you're trying to update? They will be required in order to replicate the issue.

Comment: I edited the inital post with these informations. Thanks

Comment: @BenChaff Looking at your code I noticed a type in the command which you're running. I tried using it and was like "oh that isn't working...oh it isn't quite right".